# Social Media icons, not centering inside of div

Tags: html, css, centering

not sure why, but I can't get the icons centered on the page without using padding-left:130px;

Which isn't ideal of course because the icons don't center properly when you re-size the browser window. Maybe I need more coffee, but I could use some stacker help this morning!

**http://towerdive.net/**

HTML

```
<div id="center2">
    <div id="social_icons">
        <p>
            Thanks for your interest in our blog!
            You can also find us here, as well as subscribe to our newsletter:
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li id="facebook">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Towerdive/497721103607131" title="Like us on Facebook"><img src="img/icon_facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/></a>
            </li>
            <li id="twitter">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/TowerDiveDotNet" title="Follow us on Twitter"><img src="img/icon_twitter.png" alt="Twitter"/></a>
            </li>
            <li id="newsletter">
                <a href="http://eepurl.com/uY5m9" title="Subscribe to our Newsletter"><img src="img/icon_newsletter.png" alt="Newsletter"/></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#center2 {
    width: 100%;
}

#social_icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}

#social_icons p {
    color: #e3cda4;
}

#social_icons ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#social_icons ul li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Let me know if you guys need the full HTML or CSS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **display:inline-block** for this. Write Like this:

```
#social_icons ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it, and that was fast hehe another min before I can check your answer...

Answer (score 0):

You currently use floats to display your navigational list horizontally. You can't align the list-items in the middle of the unordered lists because of the floats.

Another technique is instead of `float: left;` using `display: inline-block;`. The list-items will be displayed horizontally but also all extra white-space will taken into account. You'll get extra margins between the items (like 4px). Now you can use `text-align: center;` on the UL to center the list-items.

There are several (easy) workouts described in this article by Chris Coyier:
http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thanks for that tip as well!